# Split string in a list of labels/values with different separators and value contents

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with a list of variable/values eg.

```
string = " var1 = 20, var2  = hello    var3 =345.34  var4 = I have lost 
2,5 billions, var5 = Bill"
```

the separation of tuples can be "," or any number of spaces, the identification of tuples is always "=" 
the challenge is some values containing a descriptive string with commas as a separator of thousands or worst as a digit separator.

I tried with a sequence of re.sub and re.findall with python regex, but I can't split correctly the var4 tuple, below the code :

```
import re
string = " var1 = 20, var2  = hello    var3 =345.34  var4 = I lost 2,5 
billions, var5 = Bill"

t = re.sub('(\=\s+)', '=', string)
t = re.sub('(\s+\=)', '=', t)
result = re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9(,)\=\.]+", t)

print(result)
['var1=20,', 'var2=hello', 'var3=345.34', 'var4=I', 'lost', '2,5', 
'billions,', 'var5=Bill']
```

My expected result is

```
['var1=20', 'var2=hello', 'var3=345.34', 'var4=I lost 2,5 billions', 'var5=Bill']
```

Comment: Is there a line break in the string? Or did you mean to write `"""..."""`? Or is it just formatting in the question?

Comment: No , there are no line break on string, is just my formatting problem on posting a question, sorry

Comment: Ok, try `result = re.split(r'\s+(?=\w+=)', re.sub(r'\s*=\s*', '=', s.strip()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.split(r',?\s+(?=\w+=)', re.sub(r'\s*=\s*', '=', s.strip()))
```

The `re.sub(r'\s*=\s*', '=', s.strip())` will remove whitespaces around `=` after stripping leading/trailing whitespaces in the string and `r',?\s+(?=\w+=)'` with `re.split` will split the string at an optional comma, then 1 or more whitespaces that are followed with 1+ word chars and then `=`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bf8TEm):

```
import re
s = " var1 = 20, var2  = hello    var3 =345.34  var4 = I lost 2,5 billions, var5 = Bill"
result = re.split(r",?\s+(?=\w+=)", re.sub(r'\s*=\s*', '=', s.strip()))
print(result)
# => ['var1=20', 'var2=hello', 'var3=345.34', 'var4=I lost 2,5 billions', 'var5=Bill']
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is the tuples name=value can be separated on a string by commas or any number of spaces, and commas can be inside value too, like var4 value -> "I lost 2,5 billion" , but the separation from var4  and var5 is comma too .... billions, var5 = Bill

Comment: @Alex Share the string that you have trouble splitting with my approach, and specify the expected result.

Comment: string = " var1 = 20, var2  = hello    var3 =345.34  var4 = I lost 2,5 billions, var5 =Bill"

Comment: result = ['var1=20', 'var2=hello', 'var3=345.34', 'var4=I lost 2,5 billions', 'var5=Bill'] as you see, var4 don't contain comma at end, because the separation between var4 and var5 is comma plus space

Comment: @Alex Updated to match these new requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If every element you want to extract starts with `var` you could  use that fact following way:

```
import re
string = " var1 = 20, var2  = hello    var3 =345.34  var4 = I have lost 2,5 billions, var5 = Bill"
vars = re.findall(r'var.*?(?=var|$)',string)
print(vars) # ['var1 = 20, ', 'var2  = hello    ', 'var3 =345.34  ', 'var4 = I have lost 2,5 billions, ', 'var5 = Bill']
```

I used so-called positive lookahead (kind of zero length assertion), so `findall` is looking for substrings followed by `var` or end of `str` (`$`). As you might see `str`s inside `vars` still need some cleaning. Remove trailing spaces first:

```
vars = [i.strip(' ') for i in vars]
print(vars) # ['var1 = 20,', 'var2  = hello', 'var3 =345.34', 'var4 = I have lost 2,5 billions,', 'var5 = Bill']
```

Now your example is unclear for me - I do not know if you want to retain trailing `,`s as in `var1 = 20,` or remove it as in `var4=I lost 2,5 billions` - so I am retaining `,`s as they are noting that they might be removed in same way as shown for spaces.
Finally to remove spaces around `=` you might use `re.sub` following way:

```
vars = [re.sub(r' *= *','=',i,1) for i in vars]
print(vars) #['var1=20,', 'var2=hello', 'var3=345.34', 'var4=I have lost 2,5 billions,', 'var5=Bill']
```

Note that `1` in `re.sub` is intentional, so only `1` replacement will happen - so it will jettison spaces only around first `=` in each element of `vars`. You might drop that `1` if you are sure that in every element there is no more than 1 `=`.

Comment: I want to retain comma if is inside a value of a tuple variable=value, like in "2,5" of var4 value,  but not if is at the end of a tuple as separator.

Comment: No, the variable name change on a string, the only constant is a separation from variable name and the value, and is   <any number of spaces>=<any number of spaces> the separator in my example are spaces or comma, but spaces and commas can be inside a value too